# How do I install the "Graph Algorithms" extension in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to use the neo4j algo.algorithms. I am running neo4j desktop verison on Windows.

I tried to install the graph algorithms extension following these instructions: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/introduction/

But I ran into a problem immediately since there is no install option: 
[image]

How can I install Graph Algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Install` option does not appear for a Plugin, that means that there is no version of that Plugin compatible with the neo4j installation that you are configuring.

The latest version of the [Graph Algorithms plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms) currently available is compatible with neo4j version 3.5 (and does not even seem to work with all 3.5.x versions).

As of now, `neo4j 3.5.14` seems to be the most recent version of neo4j that works with the latest Graph Algorithms plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems like maybe I need to download Neo4J community server instead of desktop in order to get neo4j 3.5.14 and get access the Graph Algorithms plugin.